# Xcode 12.2 Crashes on launch

Tags: xcode, xcode12

After deleting `~/Library/Developer` while attempting to resolve this issue (https://github.com/xcpretty/xcode-install/issues/435).

I am unable to launch xcode.
I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall xcode, both manually and using xcpretty.

I'm attempting to launch xcode 12.2 and I'm currently running MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

When I launch xcode I see an error stating that

> Xcode quit unexpectedly.
> Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed
> information and send a report to apple.
> "

The following is the information in the bug report

```
Process:               Xcode [24484]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               12.4 (17801)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-17801000000000000~7 (12D4e)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       839994694
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [24484]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2021-06-14 10:09:31.331 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H2)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.2 (18P4347)
Anonymous UUID:        D6C1DFF4-7DB6-8ECB-43AC-F7CBB04C2AD5

Sleep/Wake UUID:       697D3CD9-6369-4728-97C6-7E37625B3BA0

Time Awake Since Boot: 46000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        10  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimServiceContext.profileQueue

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x9] <unknown>

Application Specific Information:
dyld: in dlopen()
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderKit.framework/IDEInterfaceBuilderKit
ProductBuildVersion: 12D4e

Dyld Error Message:
  can't resolve symbol _rosetta_is_current_process_translated in /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator because dependent dylib #1 could not be loaded

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: DVTPlugInExtensionFaultingLock
0   dyld                            0x000000010bf0afce __fcntl + 10
1   dyld                            0x000000010bf09644 fcntl + 171
2   dyld                            0x000000010bece4d5 ImageLoaderMachO::loadCodeSignature(linkedit_data_command const*, int, unsigned long long, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 423
3   dyld                            0x000000010bed4414 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 276
4   dyld                            0x000000010becd628 ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 158
5   dyld                            0x000000010beb8ee5 dyld::loadPhase6(int, stat const&, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) + 728
6   dyld                            0x000000010bec0b41 dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 1422
7   dyld                            0x000000010bec0551 dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 185
...
   r8: 0x000070000fde18b0   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000014  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000014  r13: 0x000070000fde1cb0  r14: 0x0000000000000009  r15: 0x0000000000000006
  rip: 0x000000010bf0aede  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x000000011d4cd000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000209
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x100138000 -        0x10013bff7  com.apple.dt.Xcode (12.4 - 17801) <96564365-DC0B-397C-BF24-E152CBE2F30A> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x100150000 -        0x10017ffff  com.apple.dt.DVTCocoaAdditionsKit (12.4 - 17800) <7706C0EC-638B-397F-8058-39405CC58BF7> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTCocoaAdditionsKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTCocoaAdditionsKit
       0x1001bc000 -        0x1007cbfff  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (12.4 - 17800) <139CC330-72B1-31EE-9545-286B9D959209> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
       0x100ae4000 -        0x100c7ffff  com.apple.dt.DVTKit (12.4 - 17800) <F8715548-9981-3524-8A8F-CA69C645F497> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
       0x100ddb000 -        0x101692fff  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation (12.4 - 17801) <94BF4338-F3CA-3D81-87F1-7A50E6779ED1> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
       0x101e9e000 -        0x102889ff7  com.apple.dt.IDEKit (12.4 - 17801) <1BA720BC-33B3-393E-A824-7F1A42394116> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
       0x103188000 -        0x103223fd3  com.apple.SymbolicationDT (12.4 - 64543.1) <81C083E6-CE69-362F-A4EB-B0595F268B89> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/SymbolicationDT.framework/Versions/A/SymbolicationDT
       0x103296000 -        0x1032d5ffb  com.apple.DebugSymbols (195.1 - 195.1) <2026D91E-F119-3231-A274-F197ECADFA65> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DebugSymbolsDT.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbolsDT
       0x103328000 -        0x1033e3ff7  com.apple.CoreSymbolicationDT (12.4 - 64543.1) <FBF19064-1D62-33CB-B60B-99D9CB5D2D8E> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/CoreSymbolicationDT.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolicationDT
       0x10345c000 -        0x103487ffb  com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices (12.4 - 64543.2) <1A4AF5BE-8206-3877-9ECA-784A23BE2FCE> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework/Versions/A/DTXConnectionServices
       0x1034b4000 -        0x10357bfff  com.apple.dt.instruments.DVTInstrumentsFoundation (12.4 - 64543.2) <41E65559-8110-3A37-A352-91BAF6FE0058> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTInstrumentsFoundation
       0x10363c000 -        0x103643ff7  com.apple.MallocStackLogging (1.0 - 1) 

...

    0x7fff68123000 -     0x7fff68125fff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (62.100.2) <F80872AA-E1FD-3D7E-8729-467656EC6561> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff68126000 -     0x7fff6812dffb  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (1238.120.1) <5820A2AF-CE72-3AB3-ABCC-273A3419FB55> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fff6812e000 -     0x7fff68144ff2  libsystem_trace.dylib (1147.120) <04B47629-847B-3D74-8ABE-C05EF9DEEFE4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff68146000 -     0x7fff6814bff7  libunwind.dylib (35.4) <42B7B509-BAFE-365B-893A-72414C92F5BF> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff6814c000 -     0x7fff68181ffe  libxpc.dylib (1738.140.1) <3E243A41-030F-38E3-9FD2-7B38C66C35B1> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 113232
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.1G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.1G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=191.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=191.1M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               256K        2 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                 1232K        2 
CoreGraphics                         8K        1 
CoreImage                           24K        2 
CoreServices                        84K        1 
CoreUI image data                  116K        1 
Dispatch continuations            24.0M        1 
Foundation                           4K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           146.9M       83 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        6 
Performance tool data                4K        1         not counted in TOTAL below
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       15 
Stack                             15.1M       15 
VM_ALLOCATE                        380K       15 
__DATA                            79.1M      639 
__DATA_CONST                      4679K      117 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       475.8M      194 
__OBJC_RO                         32.3M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         1904K        1 
__TEXT                           648.7M      617 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
mapped file                       58.8M       17 
shared memory                      644K       16 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.5G     1751 

Model: MacBookPro16,1, BootROM 1554.80.3.0.0 (iBridge: 18.16.14347.0.0,0), 6 processors, 6-Core Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_IntelUHDGraphics630Item, Intel UHD Graphics 630, spdisplays_builtin
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro5300MItem, AMD Radeon Pro 5300M, spdisplays_pcie_device, 4 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2667 MHz, Micron, 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2667 MHz, Micron, 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x7BF), wl0: Apr  7 2020 13:09:12 version 9.30.357.41.32.5.49 FWID 01-617711e7
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.6f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: USB 10/100/1000 LAN, Ethernet, en7
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
USB Device: USB3.1 Hub
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB 2.0 BILLBOARD
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB Billboard Device
USB Device: USB2.1 Hub
USB Device: Apple T2 Bus
USB Device: Composite Device
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Touch Bar Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 55.3
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 55.3
```

Comment: Oof. I recently accidentally deleted some files inside `~/Library/Developer` (not the whole folder, though) and lost all my code snippets.

Comment: Same problem here. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you really removed the problematic `CoreSimulator.framework`? You are still getting the _can't resolve symbol _rosetta_is_current_process_translated_ error, which comes from the more recent `CoreSimulator.framework` that can only be run on BigSur or newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you `rm` `/Library/Developer` or `~/Library/Developer`? I found the culprit to be `/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework`, which gets installed if you try to install Xcode 12.5 in MacOS Catalina using [xcode-install](https://github.com/xcpretty/xcode-install) even when that version needs BigSur. I was able to solve the problem by deleting it, and then reinstalling a proper version of Xcode, which reinstalls a working version of `CoreSimulator.framework`.

You are still getting this error:

```
can't resolve symbol _rosetta_is_current_process_translated in /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator
```

and this seems to suggest you still have the problematic `CoreSimulator.framework` in place.

Comment: This could very well be the case, I may have used the wrong path. Unfortunately I'm still not able to open xcode after deleting `/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework`. This could be because I managed to dig a deeper whole while trying to fix the original problem :P. Thanks for your help I'll upvote for now, and accept once I can confirm that this fixes the issue

Comment: I guess you are now getting a different error... or are you getting the same? Maybe you can try to fix it using the tools in the Recovery Mode?